# Passing variable from javascript to flash

Tags: javascript, flash, actionscript

I have a flash music player that I would like to accept a parameter via a button click on a website.  I'm thinking I could do this with javascript but not sure how.

Does anybody have any sample code for both the javascript and what I would use to request the variable inside my actionscript code?

Thanks, I appreciate it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://painteddigital.com/2008/calling-flash-as3-functions-from-javascript/

In the flash add a callback for the javascript function:

```
import flash.external.ExternalInterface;
ExternalInterface.addCallback("sendTextToFlash", getTextFromJavaScript);
function getTextFromJavaScript(str):void {
    trace(str);
}
```

In the html/js call it:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var currentPage="Home";
    function setCurrentPage(newPage) {
        currentPage = newPage;
        SendDataToFlashMovie(newPage);
    }
```

Calling JS Function From Flash: getURL("javascript:myfunction();");

Comment: I'm having a hard time getting that guys code to work.  I have FlashBug running and I'm looking for a trace.  Nothing is happening.  What's supposed to happen when you click the home button?

Comment: Here is my dev page if you're interested in looking:

http://rt.jaxna.com/index.html

Answer (score 1):

You're going to utilize the flash.external.ExternalInterface class.

Adobe docs:
http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/external/ExternalInterface.html

A simple google search for "AS3 ExternalInterface example" will yield more than enough results to point you in the right direction.